# Camera Barcode Scanning Works on iPhone, But Not iPad

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, barcode, avcapturesession

I'm using AVCaptureDevice API for scanning barcode and it works very well on iPhone, but very similar code I have doesn't work on iPad and I'm not quite sure why (not detecting any barcode at all). The main differences are the size of scan area, position and orientation. I tested using iPhone 12 mini (iOS 15 beta) and the original iPad Pro 9.7" (iOS 14.6). Not sure if that matters.

Below is the code for the scanner. Please let me know if you noticed something that should be changed.

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ScannerViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate {
    var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
    var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!
    var barcodeCallback: (String) -> Void
    var cameraScanDismissedCallback: (Bool) -> Void
    var scanned = false
    var currentDevice: AVCaptureDevice!
    var scanRectView: UIView!

    init(barcodeCallback: @escaping (String) -> Void, cameraScanDismissedCallback: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        self.barcodeCallback = barcodeCallback;
        self.cameraScanDismissedCallback = cameraScanDismissedCallback;
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr, .ean8, .ean13, .pdf417, .code128, .aztec, .code39, .code39Mod43, .code93, .dataMatrix, .face, .interleaved2of5, .itf14, .upce]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }
    
        let windowSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    
        var scanSize: CGSize!;
        var scanRect: CGRect!;
        if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
            scanSize = CGSize(width:windowSize.width*1/3, height:windowSize.width*1/7);
            scanRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - scanSize.width/2,
                          y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY - scanSize.height/2,
                          width:scanSize.width, height:scanSize.height);
        }else{
            scanSize = CGSize(width:windowSize.width*2/3, height:windowSize.width*1/3);
            scanRect = CGRect(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - scanSize.width/2,
                          y: UIScreen.main.bounds.midY - scanSize.height/2,
                          width:scanSize.width, height:scanSize.height);
        }
    
        scanRect = CGRect(x:scanRect.origin.y/windowSize.height,
                      y:scanRect.origin.x/windowSize.width,
                      width:scanRect.size.height/windowSize.height,
                      height:scanRect.size.width/windowSize.width);
        metadataOutput.rectOfInterest = scanRect

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
    
        if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
            let orientation: UIDeviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation
            previewLayer.connection?.videoOrientation = {
                switch (orientation) {
                case .faceUp:
                    return .landscapeLeft
                case .portrait:
                    return .portrait
                case .landscapeRight:
                    return .landscapeLeft
                case .landscapeLeft:
                    return .landscapeRight
                default:
                    return .portrait
                }
            }()
        }
    
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
    
        scanRectView = UIView();
        view.addSubview(self.scanRectView)
        scanRectView.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: scanSize.width,
                                     height: scanSize.height);
    
        if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
            scanRectView.center = CGPoint( x:UIScreen.main.bounds.midX - scanSize.width/2,
                                            y:UIScreen.main.bounds.midY - scanSize.height/2)
        }else{
            scanRectView.center = CGPoint( x:UIScreen.main.bounds.midX,
                                       y:UIScreen.main.bounds.midY)
        }
    
        scanRectView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.yellow.cgColor
        scanRectView.layer.borderWidth = 5;

        currentDevice = videoCaptureDevice
        captureSession.startRunning()
        toggleTorch(on: true)
    }

    func toggleTorch(on: Bool) {
        guard let device = currentDevice else { return }

        if device.hasTorch {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration()
            
                if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
                    device.videoZoomFactor = 1.3
                }else{
                    device.videoZoomFactor = 1.5
                }

                if on == true {
                    device.torchMode = .on
                } else {
                    device.torchMode = .off
                }

                device.unlockForConfiguration()
            } catch {
                print("Torch could not be used")
            }
        } else {
            print("Torch is not available")
        }
    }

    func failed() {
        let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Scanning not supported", message: "Your device does not support scanning a code from an item. Please use a device with a camera.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
        present(ac, animated: true)
        captureSession = nil
        toggleTorch(on: false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == false) {
            captureSession.startRunning()
            toggleTorch(on: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        if (captureSession?.isRunning == true) {
            captureSession.stopRunning()
            toggleTorch(on: false)
        }
    
        cameraScanDismissedCallback(scanned)
    }

    func metadataOutput(_ output: AVCaptureMetadataOutput, didOutput metadataObjects: [AVMetadataObject], from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        captureSession.stopRunning()

        if let metadataObject = metadataObjects.first {
            guard let readableObject = metadataObject as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject else { return }
            guard let stringValue = readableObject.stringValue else { return }
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate))
            found(code: stringValue)
            scanned = true
        }

        dismiss(animated: true)
    }

    func found(code: String) {
        print(code)
        barcodeCallback(code)
    }

    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){
            return .landscape
        }else{
            return .portrait
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does 'doesn't work' mean?  How does it not work?  Does your iPad get a camera screen?  Does AVCaptureSession stop when it recognize the barcode but does not return a thing?

Comment: Yes, it's just not detecting the barcode at all. Otherwise, the view shows up and the scanned area (yellow box) also displayed as expected. The session just keeps running because it's not able to detect. I have tried turning the barcode up-side-down, scan outside the scan area, etc and it still cannot detect the barcode.

Comment: You have a few lines with 'if(UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad){.'  Why don't you see what happens without them?  There are people who use `AVCaptureSession` to scan the barcode with iPad.  So it's not the matter of using iPhone or iPad for sure.

Comment: @LeoDabus is definitely right.  The doc says "Even if the device has a torch, that torch might not be available for use. Thus, you should also check the value of the isTorchAvailable property before using it."

Comment: iPad definitely has a torch and it's working as expected, but yes I probably should check regardless. @ElTomato as for the iPad check, I tried that already at the beginning and I kept playing around since the positioning is slightly different from when it's executed on iPhone.

Comment: It turns out that the video orientation was the issue so I fixed that, but now I'm not able to center the scanRect since I don't know how to get the size of the modal. Is there an easy way to get the width and height of the modal when it's not full screen?

Comment: "Is there an easy way to get the width and height of the modal when it's not full screen?"  That's not what you have opened your topic for according to the title.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone ran into a similar issue, check for the following:

1. Orientation of the video
2. The position of AVCaptureMetadataOutput.rectOfInterest

I'm still having an issue with the rectOfInterest not positioned at the center, but it works. Once I can figure out how to center it, I will post the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

it isn't center probably because of your navigationBar.
Try set rectOfInterest as below, remember that camer use different coordinate than UIView, posX and posY are in UIView coordinates

```
let aimRect = CGRect(x: (posY - navBar.height) / UIScreen.main.bounds.height,
                     y: posX / UIScreen.main.bounds.width,
                     width: rectHeight / UIScreen.main.bounds.height,
                     height: rectWidth / UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
```